# Ordering the Amount range values (Ascending Order )in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

Hi I want to show the Result set in ascending order. I have created the [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9d4d9/1) for the same.

```
select amount_range as amount_range, count(*) as number_of_items,
  sum(amount) as total_amount
from (
  select *,case
    when amount between 0.00 and 2500.00 then '<=$2,500.00'
    when amount between 2500.01 and 5000.00 then '$2,500.01 - $5,000.00'
    when amount between 5000.01 and 7500.00 then '$5,000.01 - $7,500.00'
    when amount between 7500.01 and 10000.00 then '$7,500.01 - $10,000.00'
    else '>$10,000.01' end as amount_range
  from Sales ) a
group by amount_range order by amount_range;
```

My Results should be like

```
<=$2,500.00          4  5000
$2,500.01 - $5,000.00     3  12000
$5,000.01 - $7,500.00   2    13000
$7,500.01 - $10,000.00  1    10000
>$10,000.01             1   15000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method will be to sort off of a value in each grouping, for example the minimum `amount`:

```
select amount_range as amount_range,
  count(*) as number_of_items,
  sum(amount) as total_amount
from (
  select *,case
    when amount between 0.00 and 2500.00 then '<=$2,500.00'
    when amount between 2500.01 and 5000.00 then '$2,500.01 - $5,000.00'
    when amount between 5000.01 and 7500.00 then '$5,000.01 - $7,000.00'
    when amount between 7500.01 and 10000.00 then '$7,500.01 - $10,000.00'
    else '>$10,000.01' end as amount_range
  from Sales ) a
group by amount_range
order by min(amount);
```

In Postgres, your subquery could also return an array where the first element is the desired position and the second is the string describing the bucket. Then, the outer query can `ORDER BY` your positioning value.

```
select amount_range[2] as amount_range,
  count(*) as number_of_items,
  sum(amount) as total_amount
from (
  select *,case
    when amount between 0.00 and 2500.00 then ARRAY['1','<=$2,500.00']
    when amount between 2500.01 and 5000.00 then ARRAY['2','$2,500.01 - $5,000.00']
    when amount between 5000.01 and 7500.00 then ARRAY['3', '$5,000.01 - $7,000.00']
    when amount between 7500.01 and 10000.00 then ARRAY['4', '$7,500.01 - $10,000.00']
    else ARRAY['5','>$10,000.01'] end as amount_range
  from Sales ) a
group by amount_range
order by amount_range[1];
```

The first method happens to be simpler for your example. The second method would be useful if you were bucketing by something more complicated than ranges.